# How to implement functions which act as instance method as well as class methods in python?

Tags: python, pandas, design-patterns, class-design

I am working on a class which represents a stock portfolio. I have been implementing this by extending over `pandas.DataFrame`. I have been writing some generic portfolio analyzing visualizations. Till now I have a module with all visualization functions which can be used as

```py
visualization1(portfolio_instance ,*args, **kwargs)
```

I did wrap them to be used as instance methods like

```py
def visualization(self, *args, **kwargs):
       from module import visualziation1

        return visualziation1(self.data, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I am pretty sure there is a better way for this

How are these implemented in standard library like pandas for e.g.

```py
df_inst_1.merge(df_inst_2, on = 'something', how= 'left' )
```

and

```py
pd.merge(df_inst_1, df_inst_2, on ='something', how = 'left')
```

Comment: I hope my answer cleared that for you. If so please mark it as correct and/or upvote it if not let my know what is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Navigating through these huge codebase are huge challenge for me. Any pointers on that front?

Comment: I use an IDE which can quickly navigate me to any function,method or class definition of any installed library with a single ctrl+click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the same way you do it (well not exactly) note that `pd` is not a class object it is a module. So you have a function declared in a module aka a simple function object and an instance method declared on a class so there is no clashing of names in respective scopes. So you import the function and pass `self` as a first parameter just as you did it. So pandas use a function in a module and an instance method on a class which is allowed.

Quick look into pandas module reveals that, exert from `DataFrame` class below with my comment:

```
    @Substitution('')
    @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=2)
    def merge(self, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None,
              left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=False,
              suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False,
              validate=None):
        from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge # Here we import a normal function and pass self as first parameter
        return merge(self, right, how=how, on=on, left_on=left_on,
                     right_on=right_on, left_index=left_index,
                     right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
                     copy=copy, indicator=indicator, validate=validate)
```

Creating class method and instance method with the same name is not possible to my knowledge, one will shadow the other.

```
class TestClass:
    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        print("class")

    def fun(self):
        return print("instance")


TestClass.fun()
```

This will yield: `TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

As our second function declaration shadowed the previous one.

And if you change the order in which you declare functions:

```
class TestClass:

    def fun(self):
        return print("instance")


    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        print("class")



TestClass().fun()
```

You will get output `>>class`